# How to use connect-proxy on CygWin

Tags: linux, proxy, cygwin, node.js

I am trying to run a node.js program behind a corporate firewall. However, I am unable to explicitly tell node.js which proxy to use and therefore all my external connections time out.

I read on a some post that I could use **connect-proxy** as an HTTP proxy for my tunneling needs, but I have no idea how to actually use it.

I want to run the following:
`$ node program.js`
using **connect-proxy**.

The only command I was able to get so far is this:
`$ connect-proxy -H myproxy.com:8083 google.com

GET

HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.com/

...`

Answer (score 0):

Before going further it is worth trying the environment variable that a number of other languages and tools support.

`export http_proxy=http://proxyserver:port`

Often they use port 8080 but check the Javascript in the PAC file loaded by your browser to be sure.

If that produces a different result but still doesn't connect, you probably need to do NTLM auth with the proxy and the only way I know to do this is to run NTLMAPS before running your app. If you are really interested in getting this working transparently, then porting NTLMAPS to Javascript should do the trick.